# Cell/column/row divider between formula/import result

Tags: google-sheets, concatenation, array-formulas, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

> This is a Google Sheets case, but if you good enough with MS Excel and
>   know the solution, don't be shy and share it with the community. Your
>   experience could be relevant to all of us.

Hello over there! I still didn't find any relevant solution in google, so I post my problem here.

I have a sample sheet and I import data via formula to cell via:
`=UNIQUE(INDIRECT(C$2&"!"&$O3)`
which means import all unique values via formula from Sheet!Range:range

It works fine, and I receive necessary data like:
[image: formula]

But I want to see it like this:[image: range space]

with X (1,2,3,etc) row/cell/column spaces between them. I guess that `=SPLIT` formula should help me with that, but when I use `,` as a separator, I receive only first value, not the whole array of results that I needed it to.

So is there any way to achieve the result that I show at the picture above via formula or `Google Script`?

> SAMPLE TEST SHEET with EDIT permission here: 
>   https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eYeFI8nL39kLNDkcyyjeqV8tc9LwG7P7cn2NzUIB7Wo

Comment: @player0 I updated the first post with sample sheet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(
 "♂"&UNIQUE(INDIRECT(F$2&"!"&$G2))&"♂♀",,999^99), "♂")), "♀", ""))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: btw, the only thing I didn't understand, why do we use a special characters? Is it like a separator for for `split`?

Comment: "separator" is not a fixed (predetermined) value. it can be anything you wish but it's best if it's a unique character. such one that does not exist in your dataset - ♦♣♠♥♀♫♂♪◄↕... etc.